# How to move flask wtform from extending view to extended view and instantiate forms for all views?

Tags: python, flask, wtforms, flask-wtforms

To make my question clearer, here is a little application that takes a sentence input and outputs that sentence twice.

I have `base.html`:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title> My site </title>
    <body>
    {% block content %}{% endblock %}
   </body>
</html>
```

and `index.html`:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
{{ s }}
<form action="" method="post" name="blah">
    {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
    {{ form.sentence(size=80) }}
    <input type="submit" value="Doubler"></p>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

Here is part of `views.py`:

```
from forms import DoublerForm

@app.route('/index')
def index():
    form = DoublerForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        s = form.sentence.data
        return render_template('index.html', form=form, s=str(s) + str(s))
    return render_template('index.html', form=form, s="")
```

And here is `forms.py`, without all the imports:

```
class DoublerForm(Form):
    sentence = StringField(u'Text')
```

This seems to work OK. But what I would like is to have my input form in the `base.html` template so that this shows up on all pages that extend it, not just the `index` page. How can I move the form to the base.html and instantiate the form for all views that extend base.html?

Answer (score 3):

[You can use the flask.g object and `flask.before_request`.](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#flask.Flask.before_request)

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, g
from flask_wtf import Form
from wtforms import StringField

@app.before_request
def get_default_context():
    """
    helper function that returns a default context used by render_template
    """
    g.doubler_form = DoublerForm()
    g.example_string = "example =D"

@app.route('/', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def index():
    form = g.get("doubler_form")
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        s = form.sentence.data
        return render_template('index.html', form=form, s=str(s) + str(s))
    return render_template('index.html', form=form, s="")
```

You can also explicitly define a context function

```
def get_default_context():
    """
    helper function that returns a default context used by render_template
    """
    context = {}
    context["doubler_form"] = form = DoublerForm()
    context["example_string"] = "example =D"
    return context
```

and is used like this

```
@app.route('/faq/', methods=['GET'])
def faq_page():
    """
    returns a static page that answers the most common questions found in limbo
    """
    context = controllers.get_default_context()
    return render_template('faq.html', **context)
```

Now, you'll have whatever objects you add to the context dictionary available in all templates that unpack the context dictionary.

index.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
{{ s }}
{% endblock %}
```

base.html

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title> My site </title>
    <body>
    {% block content %}{% endblock %}
    <form action="" method="post" name="blah">
      {{ doubler_form.hidden_tag() }}
      {{ doubler_form.sentence(size=80) }}
      {{ example_string }}
      <input type="submit" value="Doubler"></p>
    </form>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: No. I would like the form to be embedded in `base.html` so that it automatically gets show in all pages that extend it.

Comment: Do you want the form to be used in index or can it happen after the content block like my edit shows?

Comment: It doesn't need to be used in index, but now where is the `form` object coming from? In my code it was instantiated in `index()`; I don't want to have to instantiate it in all other functions that extend `base.html`.

Comment: Ahh, that's a very different question.

Comment: Your new solution makes sense, but it still seems a bit redundant to me to have to call `get_default_context()` from every view function.

Comment: @theQman Just wanted to check in. Does my update seem less redundant?

Comment: I would like to know if there is a way to it with less redundancy. Maybe create a decorator could be a solution.